# Centrifugal force in the two body problem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, gravity, potential-energy, centrifugal-force

In the two body problem, the [Effective radial potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity#Effective_radial_potential_energy) in general relativity is given by

$$
V(r)=-\frac{G M m}{r}+\frac{L^{2}}{2\mu r^{2}}-\frac{G(M+m)L^{2}}{c^{2}\mu r^{3}}
$$
where the second term is the centrifugal potential energy.

1. Firstly, I am a little bit confused about the second term because from my study of classical physics the centrifugal term only arises if we solve the equations in a rotated frame reference however the second term seem to appear even without that assumption. For example when one finds the [potential energy in a schwartzchild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Effective_radial_potential_energy) the second term seems to appear too. Am I missing something here?
2. Secondly, In a [rotated frame of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame#Newton.27s_second_law_in_the_two_frames) two "fictitious" forces appear the centrifugal force 
   $$
   F_{cent}=-m\,\Omega\times(\Omega\times r)
   $$
   and the Coriolis force
   $$
   F_{Cor}=-m\,\Omega\times\frac{dr}{dt}
   $$
   Is $F_{cent}$ equal to the derivative of the second term in $V(r)$ and if so then how because they look very different to me?

Comment: The equation of motion for the 2-body problem is usually given in the frame with the centre of mass at rest. How did you reach the conclusion that it is rotating?

Answer (score 1):

1. The centrifugal potential is nothing but the angular part of the kinetic energy of the (reduced mass) particle. To see this, write the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) in polar coordinates,
   $$L=T-V=\frac{\mu}{2}\left(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2\right)-V(r).$$
   Since $\phi$ is a [cyclic coordinate](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cyclic_coordinates) its conjugated momentum (the angular momentum) is conserved
   $$p_\phi=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot\phi}=\mu r^2\dot\phi=\mbox{constant}.$$
   This relation eliminates $\dot\phi$ from the Lagrangian,
   $$L=\frac{\mu}{2}\dot r^2+\frac{p_\phi^2}{2\mu r^2}-V(r).$$
   Note that although the second term on the RHS is a kinetic term, it does not explicitly depend on velocities so it may be reinterpreted as a potential term,
   $$L=\frac{\mu}{2}\dot r^2-V(r)_{\mathrm{ef}},$$
   where the effective potential $V(r)_{\mathrm{ef}}$ is the sum of the so-called centrifugal potential and the interaction potential,
   $$V(r)_{\mathrm{ef}}=\frac{p_\phi^2}{2\mu r^2}-V(r).$$
   That is a general procedure, *whenever one has a cyclic variable one can write its associated kinetic terms without explicit velocities and thus interpret them as potential terms*.
2. The [equation of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equations_and_Hamilton.27s_principle) for the radial coordinate is
   $$\mu\ddot r=-\frac{\partial V(r)_{\mathrm{ef}}}{\partial r}=\frac{p_\phi^2}{\mu r^3}-\frac{\partial V(r)}{\partial r}.$$
   The second term on the RHS is an repulsive term and it equals the centrifugal force,
   $$\frac{p_\phi^2}{\mu r^3}=\mu r \dot\phi^2=|-\mu\vec\Omega\times(\vec\Omega\times\vec r)|,$$
   since $\vec\Omega=\dot\phi \vec e_k$